# How to select points inside the areas of a multiple polygons vector layer?

Tags: python, qgis

I wrote this code to select points within polygons using pyqgis.

```
polygonFile = '/home/polygon.shp'
pointFile = '/home/points.shp'

polygonLayer = QgsVectorLayer(polygonFile, 'poligoni', 'ogr')
pointLayer = QgsVectorLayer(pointFile, 'punti', 'ogr')

polygonFeatureList = [plfeat for plfeat in polygonLayer.getFeatures()]
pointFeatureList =  [ptfeat for ptfeat in pointLayer.getFeatures()]

polygonFeatureNumber = polygonLayer.featureCount()
pointFeatureNumber = pointLayer.featureCount()

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(polygonLayer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(pointLayer)

for ptfeat in pointFeatureList:
    ptGeometry = ptfeat.geometry()
    for plfeat in polygonFeatureList:
        plGeometry = plfeat.geometry()
        if plGeometry.contains(ptGeometry):
            pointLayer.select(ptfeat.id)
```

It works only when my polygon shapefile is compsed by only one feature, otherwise I get this error

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QgsVectorLayer.select(QgsRectangle, bool): argument 1 has unexpected type 'builtin_function_or_method'
  QgsVectorLayer.select(int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'builtin_function_or_method'
  QgsVectorLayer.select(unknown-type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

I tried to modify the last part with this:

```
for pt in (range(0, pointLayer.featureCount()):
    ptFeat = pointFeatureList[pt] 
    ptGeometry = ptFeat.geometry()
    for pl in (range(0, polygonLayer.featureCount()):
        plFeat = polygonFeatureList[pl]
        plGeometry = plFeat.geometry()
        if plGeometry.contains(ptGeometry):
            pointLayer.select(ptFeat, id)
```

but this time I get this kind of error

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QgsVectorLayer.select(QgsRectangle, bool): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsFeature'
  QgsVectorLayer.select(int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsFeature'
  QgsVectorLayer.select(unknown-type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsFeature'
```

So far I didn't find the way to make a correct use of the "select" function in a spatial query.

Comment: Do you want to select all points that are in all polygons?

Comment: Yes I do. Do you know how? Yhanks

Comment: You can look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131158/how-to-select-features-using-an-expression-with-pyqgis), it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions

This is the first

```
polygonFile = '/path/poligoni.shp'
pointFile = '/path/punti.shp'

polygonLayer = QgsVectorLayer(polygonFile, 'poligoni', 'ogr')
pointLayer = QgsVectorLayer(pointFile, 'punti', 'ogr')

polygonFeatureList = [plFeat for plFeat in polygonLayer.getFeatures()]
pointFeatureList = [ptFeat for ptFeat in pointLayer.getFeatures()]

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(polygonLayer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(pointLayer)

for ptFeat in pointFeatureList:
    ptGeom = ptFeat.geometry()
    for plFeat in polygonFeatureList:
        plGeom = plFeat.geometry()
        if plGeom.contains(ptGeom):
            pointLayer.select(ptFeat.id())
```

This is the second solution

```
import processing

polygonFile = '/path/poligoni.shp'
pointFile = '/path/punti.shp'

polygonLayer = QgsVectorLayer(polygonFile, 'poligoni', 'ogr')
pointLayer = QgsVectorLayer(pointFile, 'punti', 'ogr')

polygonFeatureList = [plFeat for plFeat in polygonLayer.getFeatures()]
pointFeatureList = [ptFeat for ptFeat in pointLayer.getFeatures()]

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(polygonLayer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(pointLayer)

processing.runalg('qgis:selectbylocation', pointLayer, polygonLayer, u'contains', 0, 0)
```